# Is proving $m(E) < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$ equivalent to prove $m(E) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, quantifiers

Definition of **measurable set**: A set $E$ measurable if $$m^*(T) = m^*(T \cap E) + m^*(T \cap E^c)$$ for every subset of $T$ of $\mathbb R$.

Definition of **Lebesgue measurable function**: Given a function $f: D \to \mathbb R ∪ \{+\infty, -\infty\}$, defined on some domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, we say that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable if $D$ is measurable and if, for each $a\in[-\infty, +\infty]$, the set $\{x\in D \mid f(x) > a\}$ is measurable.

Is proving $m(E) < \delta, \forall \delta > 0$ equivalent to prove $m(E) = 0$? $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure on measurable set.)

I have this question when I was reading Lusin theorem, that is, if $f(x)$ is a Lebesgue measurable function and finite almost everythere($m({x \in E: |f(x)| = +\infty}) = 0$), then for $\forall \delta > 0, \exists F \subset E$ where $F$ is closed, such that $f(x)$ is continuous on $F$ and $m(E - F) < \delta$. Lusin theorem can fail to work if $m(E - F) < \delta$ replaced by $m(E - F) = 0$. This made me confused coz sometimes I used $m(E) < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$ to show $m(E) = 0$ in my homework which was introduced by my professor.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Certainly. This has nothing to do with measure theory. Theorem: If $x\ge0$ and $x<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ then $x=0$. Proof: Suppose $x\ne0$. Then $x>0$,, since we're given that $x\ge0$. Let $\epsilon=x$; now the hypothesis implies $x<x$, contradiction.

Comment: However, in this case the set $F$ depends on $\delta$, which is different than the argument you quoted. So for *each* $\delta$ you can find such an $F$; there is not necessarily a single $F$ that works for *every* $\delta$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That looks like an answer.

Comment: @rogerl: I got you a little bit. Intuitively, I think a rational idea for Lusin's theorem can fail to work when $(E-F)$ being a zero measure set is that it is a function on set not the set itself. So some properties like continuous will depend both domain and what the function looks like?

Comment: Read what roger wrote again! The problem is exactly what he said. It's not what you said just now - you're talking about how Lusin doesn't work for a certain set, but there simply _is_ no such set. Lusin says "For every $\delta>0$ there exists $F$ such that etc." It does _not_ say "There exists $F$ such that for every $\delta>0$ etc". But that second misinterpretation is how you seem to be interpreting it...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I know, but see this for every $\epsilon > 0, \exists G$ where $G$ is an open set and $E \subset G$, such that $m^*(G-E) < \epsilon$ $=>$ $E =G-N$, where $G$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set and $N$ is a null set(zero measure). In fact, $G = \bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty}G_n$ and $m^*(G_n - E) < \frac{1}{n}$. Statement above is quite similar to Lusin theorem while this works fine.

Comment: There's a big difference! In that statement you cited it says for every $\delta>0$ there exists an _open_ set such that etc if and only if there exists a $G_\delta$ such that etc. A $G_\delta$ is not an open set. If you change "$G_\delta$" to "open" it's false.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Oooooh, yes. I notice the difference. Well, if I remove the closed set property in Lusin's theorem, will it definitely work on $F$ when $m(E - F) = 0$?

Comment: Whether $F$ is closed or not, that version of the theorem would show that a measurable function is continuous almost everywhere...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: This continuous can be piecewise continuous right?

Comment: "Piecewise continuous almost everywhere" doesn't make much sense as far as I can see...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I'm feeling confusing. I can find an example that is a measurable function but not continuous on any complementary of zero set. Here it is $f(x)$ is defined on $[0,1]$ with  $f(x) =1$on a Harnack set $H$ and $f(x) = -1$on $[0,1] - H$ where the Harnack set H is an extension of cantor set that is we throw length of $\frac{1}{4}$ centered in the closed interval $[0,1]$ and left $[0,\frac{3}{8}]$ and $[\frac{5}{8},1]$ and keep doing this in both closed intervals. The length of H is $\frac{1}{2}$. However, $f(x)$ can not be continuous on $[0,1] - Z$ where $\forall Z$ is a null set.

Comment: I don't see what you're confused about. It sounds to me like you're just saying that Lusin is false for $\delta=0$, which is what I've been saying all along...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Sorry. I mean my example is to show that if $F$ is not restricted to be closed in Lusin theorem, a measurable function will still fail to be continuous on $F$ where $m(E - F) = 0$. So a measurable function will not satisfy the property of continuous almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that
$$
m(E) = 0 \quad \iff \quad \forall \epsilon > 0 \, : \, m(E) < \epsilon.
$$
This has nothing to do with measure theory; it's a property of real numbers that if $x \ge 0$ is less than any positive number, then $x = 0$.

**However**, the statement of Lusin's theorem is not this. Lusin's theorem says
$$
\forall \delta > 0 \; \exists F \subset E \; : \; F \text{ is closed, } f \text{ is continuous on } F\text{, } m(E \setminus F) < \delta. \tag{1}
$$
Note that $F$ depends on $\delta$; this is is NOT the same as 
$$
\exists F \subset E \; \forall \delta > 0\; : \; F \text{ is closed, } f \text{ is continuous on } F\text{, } m(E \setminus F) < \delta. \tag{2}
$$
In (2), you can conclude that $m(E \setminus F) = 0$, but in (1) you cannot.